# Find the stationary points of w = $ −3x^2 − 4xy − y^2− 12y + 16x $ which reside at 1st quadrant

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the stationary points of 
w = $ −3x^2 − 4xy − y^2− 12y + 16x $ which reside at 1st quadrant. I did this problem with traditional method : like find $f_x$ = 0 $f_y$ = 0  and checking $f_{xx} f_{yy} - f_{xy}^2 $ which I got negative. I got the critical point as  = <-20,34>. Now how can I get a critical point on first quadrant? They've given the answer as <8/3,0>.

Comment: If you found the only critical point, and it's not in the first quadrant, then your job is easy: There are no critical points in the first quadrant.

Comment: @quasi sorry I had to add the answer. Please check again

Comment: Books have typos. Presumably the problem itself has a typo (e.g., the coefficients of $w$ are different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the needed results the question should be asked as:

What the stationary points for $f(x,y)=-3 x^2 - 4 x y - y^2 - 12 y + 16x$
 subjected to $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$ ?

In this case with the help of some slack variables $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$ to cope with the inequalities, the Lagrangian could be represented as

$$
L(x,y,\lambda,\epsilon) = f(x,y) + \lambda_1(x-\epsilon_1^2)+\lambda_2(y-\epsilon_2^2)
$$

given the stationary conditions

$$
\nabla L = \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 \lambda_1-6 x-4 y+16=0 \\
 \lambda_2-4 x-2 y-12=0 \\
 x-\epsilon_1^2=0 \\
 y-\epsilon_2^2=0 \\
 -2 \epsilon_1 \lambda_1=0 \\
 -2 \epsilon_2 \lambda_2=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Solving those conditions we obtain the  points

$$
(0,0) \;\;\; \mbox{and}\;\;\; (\frac 83,0)
$$

Attached a plot showing the stationary points

[image]

NOTE

The simple stationary points can be classified as: relative minimum, relative maximum and saddle points.

This qualification is make with the contribution of the function Hessian, considering the active restrictions, at each point. Analyzing the solutions we can say if the restrictions are active. For instance in our case

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
x & y & \lambda_1 & \lambda_2 & \epsilon_1 & \epsilon_2 \\
 0 & 0 & -16 & 12 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{8}{3} & 0 & 0 & \frac{68}{3} & \pm2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

The first point $(0,0)$ activates the two restrictions as can be observed from $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2 = 0$. The second point has only the $y = 0$ restriction active $\epsilon_2 = 0$

Comment: At the stationary point does the function obtain it's maximum or minimum value over a region?

Comment: Please give some references to the process.

Comment: Simple stationary points can be classified as relative minimum, relative maximum and saddle points. I forgot to include $(0,0)$ also as stationary point. Now it is fixed.

Comment: please give some references to the process.

Comment: @user187604 Attached some additional information. Please make me know if it is enough.

Comment: can you provide any article on it or example or YouTube video on it as reference?

Comment: @user187604 Please. Have a look at this publication http://math.cmu.edu/~cnewstea/teaching/21-256/lagrange-multipliers.pdf

Comment: thanks for helping man...